# Pushing json objects to external json file in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, file-handling

hey iam new to React and I want to push json objects being fetched from server to the external json file ..
here is how I fetched the data and stored inside a variable:

```
const fetchD = () => {
    var jsonFile= require('./globalData.json');
        let Db=[];
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/route')
            .then((response) => {
                let jsonStr = response.json();
                jsonStr.then((result) => {                 
                    for (let i in result) {
                        let Details = {
                            title: [], 
                        };
                        Details.title= result[i].course_title;   
                        Db.push(Details);     //data is present inside Db after this step 
                    }

                })
            })    
    }
export default fetchD;
```

and I have an external json file named `globalJson` with an empty array initialised and I want to push the `Details` to that external json file

Comment: The life of any object in JavaScript does not exist in a file but in memory once it has been loaded and whilst it is in scope.  Your question heading is misleading and not accurate.  What you are really asking is how to share data between resources.

Comment: @SPlatten I was asking the data stored in Db .how to store it in local file

Comment: I don't see any mention in your question of a database, the simple way is to query the data then construct a JSON object containing the response.

Comment: @SPlatten here Db is just a variable declared in my code not database after the code is executed some data is getting stored inside Db (variable) now I want to push that data into external data as mentioned

Comment: Why don't you just change the scope of Db to be outside of the fetch then notify your outside level when its done, you could do this by create a one shot timer after your code that does the push.